# Is there an easy way to implement width for `numpy.base_repr`?

Tags: python, numpy, radix

The numpy.binary_reps has the nice 'width' keyword to set the desired width of the output.
The numpy.base_repr function does instead have the weird choice 'padding' as a keyword.

Thus if i want to have a specific WIDTH of my base N output, instead of

```
np.base_repr(x,base=N,width=WIDTH)
```

i need to do

```
np.base_repr(x,base=N,padding=WIDTH-int(np.ceil(np.log(x+1)/np.log(N)))
```

which is sub-optimal to say the least. Does anybody know of a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're messing with strings anyway, just do it after?

```py
res = np.base_repr(x, base=N)
res = '0' * (WIDTH - len(res)) + res
```

Comment: For the record, I agree that `np.base_repr` should also have width and not padding. Padding is useless.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to force leading '10000...' and truncate the one :

```
base = 16
width = 10
number = 255
shift = base**width # 10...000 in base 'base'
_repr = np.base_repr(number+shift,base)[-width:]
# '00000000FF'
```